# scrolling to a list item and stop when the li is in center

Tags: jquery, html, css

hey guys i am trying to make a carousel here.
Actually i used list items and inside that images.
Now i am using scroll to scroll to a perticular list item.
but the point is, that when i click on a thumb say 2 number it scrolls to the image inside LI and sets the image to marign-left:0px;
What i want to do is to scroll to the centered image. ( image should be scrolled till centered).

Click on the 4th thumb to see the effect.

i am doing a fiddle.
[**MyFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aKEJ7/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#fourthThumb").click(function() {

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: $("#fourthImage").offset().left
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```

**how to make the scroll to stop when the 4th image is centered.**
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to make it dynamic which works for every images: [**`LIVE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/aKEJ7/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#thumbsList li").click(function() {                
        var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width()/2;
        var index = $(this).index();
        var thisImg = $("#imagesList li img:eq("+index+")");
        var imagewidth = thisImg.width()/2;
        $('html, body').animate({                    
            scrollLeft: ((thisImg.offset().left)-windowWidth+imagewidth)
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Simak That's Awesome!. Can you suggest me one thing,how can i make it responsive? i mean how should i set the ul height and imgs inside ul to fit according to container? thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Would this work in your situation?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#fourthThumb").click(function() {                
            var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width()/2;
            var imagewidth = $("#fourthImage").width()/2;
            $('html, body').animate({                    
                scrollLeft: (($("#fourthImage").offset().left)-windowWidth+imagewidth)
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aKEJ7/1/

Comment: Hey it's cool, what about if i press two or one it scrolls to center of one.

Comment: Is there a scroll rather than scrollleft to scroll to a perticular image

Comment: If you want to avoind having to retype the code for every single image, you'll have to have some sort of identifier. 
As long as the list items in the click handler are in the same order as the list items in the actual image list, you can use that to identify wich image you want to scroll to.

Comment: Can you suggest me one thing,how can i make it responsive? i mean how should i set the ul height and imgs inside ul to fit according to container? thanks anyways